# Manage Item page in Banner 7 showing blank

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php

On my staging site I witnessed a weird issue, Manage Item page in Banner 7 under Magnetothem menu is showing blank.

[image]

Comment: Anyone? The front end shows the banner images just fine however in admin panel I cannot change the images as the Manage Items page shows completely blank.

Comment: Can you please check your log files? Is any error displaying there?

Comment: No errors, but it still shows blank. Any suggestions on what should I be doing?

Comment: Uncomment this code in Index.php of Magento root and check 
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: It's extension in the directory app\code\local\Magentothem\Banner7
You can debug code in this module.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll check it and get back if this works out for me.

Comment: I have removed the comment (removed the #) as you asked from the ftp (public_html > index.php) but it is still not displaying. I have cleared the cache, reindexed but no change. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: I can check if I have your code.

Comment: Sure let me know what you need and I will share over a private platform.

Comment: Could you please let me know what you need?

Comment: Can you please create chat?

Comment: My reputation is still1 which is not enough to chat. Can you create a chat?

Comment: Go to our profile and contact us

Comment: I am trying to chat with Paul on your website, but for some reason chat window is getting disappear automatically. Not sure why.

Comment: Please email us on support@evincemage.com